# Does VirtualBox run 64-bit guests on a 32-bit host?

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization, 32-bit

Please, how can I run 64-bit guests on a 32-bit host?

I have Oracle VM Virtualbox 4.3.12.
When I choose:
[image: screenshot of the VirtualBox window to select guest machine type]

I can only find 32-bit. My host CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6600 @ 2.20GHz.

from `cat /proc/cpuinfo processor:`

> flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 constant_tsc pni monitor ssse3 bogomips

Comment: Your screenshot is from Windows version of VirtualBox. Which makes your question off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your CPU does not provide VT-x harware virtualization needed for running a 64-bit guest OS in a 32-bit host. There is nothing we can do to overcome this.

In order to still be able to run a 64-bit application (as was said in a comment) let me suggest you run Ubuntu 64-bit either by a dual-boot, or as a live system from USB. A live system in persistence mode allows to save files in a reserved area.

Alternatively it is also possible to completely install a bootable Ubuntu on a USB drive/key:

- [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Comment: Ok,i will try this solution.. Please, where can i find unbutu 12 64bits intel ? i founded only AMD which is not compatible with my host! http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/

Comment: Intel 64-bit CPUs use AM64 architecture. That's the one you need.

Comment: ok i will try ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso with USB.. Thanks  a lot.

Comment: Please i have a question, in my host i have windows 7 32bits, it's necessarly that the cpu is in 32 bits ? where can i find if my processor is 32bits or 64 bits ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's 64-bit: http://ark.intel.com/products/37255/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6600-2M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Comment: So the problem is just on the OS 32 bits ? if i install windows 7 64 bits and my vm, i can then install my tool ?

Comment: Well, it should, but I never tried. There may be issues with installing Windows 7 64-bit on that CPU, you need to do some research before you proceed.

Answer (score 4):

Support for **64-bit** guests requires CPU virtualization support in the host, A.K.A. VT-x (or AMD-v). You need to verify that your CPU has this feature.

Navigate to BIOS and enable it if it’s supported by your CPU, try to google your CPU Specs.

[Conditions for running 64-bit guests on 32-bit hosts:](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit
>   host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> - You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see Section 10.3, “Hardware vs. software virtualization”).
> - You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not
>     supported for 64-bit VMs.
> - If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the
>     particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs
>     additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon
>     explicit request.
> - On 64-bit hosts (which typically come with hardware virtualization support), 64-bit guest operating systems are always supported
>     regardless of settings, so you can simply install a 64-bit operating
>     system in the guest.
> - Warning
>
>   On any host, you should enable the I/O APIC for virtual machines
>     that you intend to use in 64-bit mode. This is especially true for
>     64-bit Windows VMs. See Section 3.3.2, “"Advanced" tab”. In addition,
>     for 64-bit Windows guests, you should make sure that the VM uses the
>     Intel networking device, since there is no 64-bit driver support for
>     the AMD PCNet card; see Section 6.1, “Virtual networking hardware”.

Comment: My CPU is: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6600 @ 2.20GHz

Comment: thats not what you should know , you should see if it support VT-x or AMD -v

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/fr/products/37255/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6600-2M-Cache-2_20-GHz-800-MHz-FSB    Technologie de virtualisation Intel® (VT-x) ‡
 No

Comment: then you could not run 64 bit system

Comment: OK, i ask, please if there is x86-64 virtual machine , i said perharps, it works on my machine ? i'm really blocked because i have to work with a tool which run only on 64bit !!!

Comment: try to download it from source then compile it

Comment: @researcher Why don't you just install Ubuntu 64-bit and use that as host?

Comment: i can't install ubuntu 64bit on my host: 32bit!