# Error i686 when installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, kernel, virtualbox

I am mounting a Virtual Box Machine to have a Ubuntu Server, the Host Machine is a Windows Server Standar 32 bits, and when I run the Machine to get the installation, i received this error message: "This Kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detectedvan i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

However, i can not find a version for this machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled Virtualization in your BIOS ? This is a requirement for running 64 bit guests, else you will have to install a 32 bit guest OS.

Comment: @SorenA wouldn't matter - they have a 32bit host OS

Comment: @ThomasWard .. ahh didn't see that. Then he have to stick with a 32 bit guest OS,

Comment: @SorenA Such as 16.04 LTS 32-bit, yes, like in Rinzwind's answer.

Comment: Related: [Virtual Box does run 64-bit guests on 32-bit host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475653/virtual-box-does-run-64-bit-guests-on-32-bit-host)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to install a 64-bit OS onto a 32-bit OS. That will not work unless you have hardware that is capable of running 64-bit (but why would you install a 32-bit system **;)** )

- Version 18.04 does not provide 32-bit installers.
- Version 16.04 does have a 32-bit installer. [You can find them here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/).

So, as a workaround, you could install 16.04 32-bit and then simply upgrade 16.04 32-bit to 18.04 32-bit.

Comment: And then you could `do-release-upgrade` on the 16.04 release and upgrade to 18.04.  Whether or not 20.04 (the next LTS) will support 32bit or not is a tossup, there's been discussions about *not* supporting 32-bit in the future, but I'm not sure where that discussion sits currently.

Comment: Yes, it is fully possible.  32-bit repositories and builds still exist, so the upgrade process works.  The only thing not produced since 18.04 is **32bit installation ISOs**.  You can confirm this by seeing the enabled architectures and builds for that release over on Launchpad's entry for [Bionic Beaver 18.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic) for the project, where `i386` is still an enabled architecture for builds.

Comment: @ThomasWard ha seems possible :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, the thing is that i need to install a Ruby on Rails app in this machine, but it is an old version and even do not have ISS to install applications, so as a solution I decided to create a Virtual Machine with Linux to do the way easier.

Comment: @SoftwareTesting no problem. Important thing to find out: is that software 32 bit? If so... install 32-bit 16.04 and do not upgrade to 18.

Comment: yes I will not upgrade, maybe in the meantime we could considere buy a new server, until, we are running a very old app and I am preparing the migration of this app.