# Install 64bit apps on 64bit machine running 32bit OS

Tags: 64-bit

I have a 64bit machine but because of some graphical troubles,i was obliged to install ubuntu 32bit.Now I need to install indesign 64bit trough Wine.Do you think there is a way to install 64bit apps on my 32bit OS as I have 64bit machine performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using 64-bit hardware and 32-bit OS, you cannot run 64-bit applications directly but you should be able to run a 64-bit OS in a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) and run your 64-bit applications in it.

For [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org/) specifically, see also:

- [64-bit Guests](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)
- [Does VirtualBox run 64-bit guests on a 32-bit host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475653/does-virtualbox-run-64-bit-guests-on-a-32-bit-host)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a 32bit OS, it is not possible to install 64bit applications. It works the other way around. You can run 32bit applications on a 64bit OS, but not 64bit application on a 32bit OS, because the 32bit OS can handle only a certain amount of instructions, whereas a 64bit OS can handle a lot more than the 32bit OS. So there will be conflict on the 32Bit OS on the processor's bus.

Comment: So I should probably run 64bit os for installing the 64bit apps...But once i install it the desktop environment just disappear and reappear repeatedly.I have an old machine.

Comment: You can try lighter version such as lubuntu or xubuntu. They work better on old hardware.