# How to run 64bit software on 32bit operating system?

Tags: 64-bit

I have a Windows software that only has 64bit version and I want to run it on my linux computer. I know I can use wine on linux but my OS is 32bit and my hardware supports 64bit I know that I can run a 64bit program on a 32bit operating system using a virtual machine but I don't know how to do it. I hope someone will show me how to do it.

Comment: Well I didn’t think that was possible but have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/475653/does-virtualbox-run-64-bit-guests-on-a-32-bit-host. Install virtual box. It’s very easy to use. YouTube is you friend for demonstrations of how to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does VirtualBox run 64-bit guests on a 32-bit host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475653/does-virtualbox-run-64-bit-guests-on-a-32-bit-host)

Comment: The OP does not mention how ram they have, which could limit how well a VM works.

Answer (score 1):

why are you running a 32bit os on 64bit hardware? you could use virtual box here is a post with some info and links

[Can I use virtualbox with a 64 Bit image in a 32 bit host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180761/can-i-use-virtualbox-with-a-64-bit-image-in-a-32-bit-host)

but if it was my computer I would just backup my files and such then reinstall my 32bit ubuntu with 64bit ubuntu as it will then use all your hardware

Comment: Other than the link, this doesn't seem to contain an actual answer.  If the link actually contains a way to do what the asker wants, you should include relevant information in your answer, in case the link rots.

Comment: I’d say reinstalling a 64 bit Ubuntu is a better solution than the solution @ryzer proposed in his question

Comment: so why is suggesting they reinstall the os with the right one for there pc not count as a answer as it would fix the problem?