# How to install virtualbox on Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit

Tags: virtualbox

How to find out the latest `VirtualBox` I can install on `Ubuntu 18.04` 32 bit system (i686)

and how to install it?

I would like to run a 64 Ubuntu in `VirtualBox`.

On `VirtualBox` webpage I have found only version for 64 bit [system](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961%7EUbuntu%7Ebionic_amd64.deb)

Comment: May be related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/475653/

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I found out from lscpu, that my CPU supports Virtualization: VT-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled "multiverse" sources, then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Comment: This will install virtualbox 5.2.42, which ends with critical error when I want to run `Lubuntu 18.04` on it. I probably need newest virtualbox.

Comment: @xralf Try a different 'paravirtualization interface' in VBox. Try KVM or Legacy. You need to change it for each VM you create. So, create the VM and then change the settings before starting it.

Comment: Try the `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` package instead

Comment: "a critical error" is vague. We cannot help you without useful data.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 the package `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` installs VirtualBox version 6.1.10, so you might want to upgrade to 20.04 if 18.04 is still serving an older version